# MSIX c# - Update and deploy on server/OneDrive

Tags: c#, installation, project, packaging, msix

**Goal:**

I am trying to make a setup file for my app. Futhermore the app must be able to be updated from a server or OneDrive.

**Solution:**

I am using **windows application packaging project** for this.

**The issue:**

The installer works fine when the installer location is on my local harddrive. But when i try to change the installer location to my online file manager or a public OneDrive folder I am unable to download and install the update or App for that matter.

**My question:**

Has anyone been able to use windows application packaging project where the app downloads updates from a server / OneDrive by uploading the installation file to a server / OneDrive and entering the path to the location, or am I on the wrong track?

**Alternatives**

The alternativ is of course to use Setup Project and perhaps AutoUpdaterDotNET (from NuGet) which works fine, but now I am interested in a solution which does not require several different third-party programs, and windows application packaging project seems to be the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating an [.appinstaller file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-auto-updates.html)? This XML file (which you can write in any code editor - you don't need VS or Advanced Installer to generate it, although that way is easier) should allow the OS to cache all the necessary information to auto-update the app accordingly.